# Has MEANjs fixed their generators for yo? (0.4.0)

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, mean, meanjs

I have been seeing that this version of meanjs generators for yo are not working. I have looked a lot into this and can't find much. Someone linked me to this: https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/commits/master

I am not that good with node or with code as I am learning , so I couldn't really find the solution in there. Or if it was there I did not know where to look or how to use it.

Just wanted to know if you guys have seen or heard anything yet.

Comment: They have a Facebook and a google group. Pretty good chance of getting a response if you post your question there.

Comment: I did so hopefully it helps!